# create hidden txt file with vbs

Tags: vbscript, hidden-files

i currently have a vbscript that creates a txt file in a directory and opens it, but id like to make it so that the file is hidden,
currtly i have this code:

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

outFile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\New map"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "test line 1" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "test line 2" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\User\Desktop\New map""")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the attribute like this

```
Const cHidden = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

outFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New map"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)
objFile.Write "test line 1" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "test line 2" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

Set mapFile = objFSO.GetFile(outFile)
mapFile.Attributes = cHidden

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Chr(34) & outFile & Chr(34)
```

Quick Reference --> https://www.thevbprogrammer.com/ch06/06-09-fso.htm
https://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html

Comment: The arg to .Run needs quotes.

Comment: Don't use [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902/692942), define the values as Named Constants. In this case `Const Hidden = 2` and `Const ReadOnly = 1` and use them like this `mapFile.Atributes = Hidden + ReadOnly`.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - I don't know what kind of file OP is creating. If its something like a batch file, the variable will not need quotes.

Comment: The fact the filename contains a space is enough for it to require double quotes encapsulating it.